# How to structure a spring boot project that doesn't interact with a database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, rest, project-structure

I have worked with Spring Boot + Data JPA and generally, the project structure would look like this

```
my-app/
├─ com.company/
│  ├─ model/
│  ├─ controller/
│  ├─ service/
│  ├─ repository/
│  ├─ MyAppMainClass.java
```

where each folder represents its function in a general sense.

```
model/ has entity classes
controller/ has controller classes that have the routes configured for the app
service/ has service classes that have the logic to process a request
repository/ has repository classes that interact with the database and get the response back
```

Now I have a very simple project where I don't have a database component, but all I need to do is call a few other REST APIs and return the response.

So should I follow the same structure and just remove the repository folder and put all the calls to the other REST APIs in the classes in the service folder?

Or is there any other structure that is generally better suited for this? Maybe if there are some inconsistencies in my understanding about all this please correct me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the repository package with a consumer package.
And create for each resource a consumer.

```
my-app/
├─ com.company/
│  ├─ model/
│  ├─ controller/
│  ├─ service/
│  ├─ consumer/
│  ├─ MyAppMainClass.java
```

Comment: **A resource for each consumer** - can you explain what a resource and consumer are? (My understanding is that a resource is a .java class and consumer is an API URL that we call . If that's the case how do I fill those classes up exactly?)

Comment: By resource i meant the definition of resource given by the rest architecture (example /api/user defines UserResource).
Consumers are your datasource instead of loading your data from database you will fetch them from an external resource.
if i had to consume a User resource, i would create a UserConsumer class that would be in charge of creating http request, handling authentication / authorization making the http call and handling any retry mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the repository package,

```
my-app/
├─ com.company/
│  ├─ model/
│  ├─ controller/
│  ├─ service/
│  ├─ MyAppMainClass.java
```